# find volume of a box using object oriented programming with c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Write a class called boxVolume with length, width and height as data members and readData(), dispData() and computeVol() as functions. Also write a main() function to test the boxVolume class.

i tried -

```
#include <iostream>

class BoxVolume
{
    public:

    float length;
    float width;
    float height;

    void readData()
    {
        using namespace std
        cout << "length: ";
        cin >> 'BoxVolume::length';
        cout << "width: ";
        cin >> 'BoxVolume::width';
        cout << "height: ";
        cin >> 'BoxVolume::height';
    }
    void computeVolume()
    {
        float volume;
        volume = 'void readData()::length' * 'void readData()::width' * 'void readData()::height';
    }

    void dispData()
    {
        using namespace std
        cout << "Volume is:" << 'void computeVolume()::volume';

    }

};

int main()
{
    BoxVolume obj1,obj2,obj3;
    obj1.readData();
    obj2.computeVolume();
    obj3.dispData();

};
```

Comment: `length * width * height`. There's a lot to unpack with this code. Aside from the extremely wrong stuff, there's a lot of bad OOP here as well. And I'm just now seeing the `main()` function. Yikes.

Comment: IMHO, using OOP to calculate the volume of a box is overkill.  Your objects would be *length*, *width*, *height* and *volume*.  Making these as separate classes or structures is overkill.  Leave them as simple numbers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the object would be a box with data members consisting of length, width, and volume. Unless you're attempting to extrapolate something from broken code.

Comment: OOP begins when you start using *late bindings*, which in C++ means *virtual functions*. Some people, including some CS teachers, think that OOP begins when you start to use classes, or encapsulation, or some other such thing; they are all wrong. (Kicking a dead horse for fun and profit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read a C++ introductory book to acquire the basics of the language first, and then start coding. I would suggest *Accelerated C++* because is shorter than its competitors but still quite complete (at the time it was published). Now it lacks support for subsequent standards in the language, from C++11 onward, so at the moment *C++ Primer* may be the best pick, although is about 1000 pages and a new edition is poised to come out in a few months. Alternatively, there is Stroustrup's *A tour of C++*. He is the creator of the language.

A compiling version of your code below, I have added encapsulation but if you don't care about making your data members public you can use a `struct` in place of a `class`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class BoxVolume
{
public:
    void readData()
    {
        cout << "length: ";
        cin >> length;
        cout << "width: ";
        cin >> width;
        cout << "height: ";
        cin >> height;
    }

    float computeVolume()
    {
        return length * width * height;
    }

    void dispData()
    {
        //using namespace std  // this is artistic I couldnt cancel it
        cout << "Volume is: " << computeVolume() << endl;

    }

private:
    float length;
    float width;
    float height;
};

int main()
{
    BoxVolume obj1,obj2,obj3;
    obj1.readData();
    obj2.computeVolume();  // data undefined for obj2
    obj3.dispData();       // data undefined for obj3
};
```

Yes I couldn't resist answering this.

Comment: Thank you so much Giogre

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//create a class named 'volume'.
class volume{
    public:
//create a constructor with the same name as class.
    volume(double length,double breadth, double height ){
   cout<<"Volume of the box is "<<length*breadth*height;
    }
};
int main()
{
    double length,breadth,height;
    cout<<"The length of the box is : ";
    cin>>length;
    cout <<"the breadth of the box is : ";
    cin>>breadth;
    cout <<"the hieght of the box is : ";
    cin>>height;
//assign the values in the constructor through keyboard. 
    volume(length,breadth,height);
}
```

Comment: Please don't throw a lump of code at the readers. Explain the idea why it is different from, and potentially better than, the other answers.